# Como actualizar una tabla dinámica con conexión a base de datos desde C#

Tags: c#, excel

Tengo una problemática la cual consiste en automatizar el envío de correos con archivos **excel** adjuntos, pero estos archivos antes deben de actualizarse con los últimos datos de una consulta a base de datos.

Investigando vi que con **C#** puedo usar unas referencias de *microsoft excel. Soy novato con esto, y he visto como es que se pueden manipular las hojas y que se puedan insertar registros en las hojas, pero no he encontrado como puedo abrir un reporte en excel y que pueda actualizar a los últimos datos que tengo.

El reporte de excel con la conexión a una base de datos ya lo tengo, pero lo que quiero es que desde **C#** me abra el archivo y actualice.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la librerías de automatización COM correspondientes a la versión de Excel que deseas automatizar por ejemplo "Microsoft Excel ##.# Object Library"

Puedes visitar la documentación disponible de Microsoft en el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/automate-excel-using-visual-c-fill-data).